# How to use the same IP for dom0 and one domU in XEN

Tags: xen

I have currently a Xen on a debian wheezy dom0. I have 6 (public) IPs and I would like to setup 6 VMs (each using one IP).

To keep access to dom0, I'd like dom0 ssh to bind on one IP port (lets say 4444). I don't really know where to start. Any pointers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I finally came up with a solution that I will details :

In this exemple, we have one physical network interface (`eth0`), 3 IPs and 3 VMs :

- `a.a.a.a` (that will be shared by dom0 and one domU called `VM_A`)
- `b.b.b.b` (for one domU `VM_B`)
- `b.b.b.c` (for one domU `VM_C`)

dom0 /etc/network/interface:

```
auto xenbr0 
iface xenbr0 inet static
    bridge_ports eth0
    address a.a.a.a
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network a.a.a.0
    broadcast a.a.a.255
    gateway a.a.a.254
```

The default vif script used in `/etc/xen/xend-config.sx` will be `(vif-script vif-bridge)`. This is for `VM_B` and `VM_C` which have their own ip.

For the configuration script of `VM_B` and `VM_C` (/etc/xen/VM_[BC].cfg) we will have :

```
vif = [ 'ip=b.b.b.b,mac=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX' ]
```

For the configuration script of `VM_A` (/etc/xen/VM_A.cfg) we will have :

```
vif = [ 'ip=192.168.0.1,script=vif-nat']
```

We have to add iptables rules in order to make `VM_A` visible to Internet :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.1 -o xenbr0  -j MASQUERADE
# One rule for each port that need to be forwarded to `VM_A`
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d a.a.a.a --dport 22 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.1:22
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d a.a.a.a --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.1:80
```

Also need to enable packet forwarding (`/etc/sysctl.conf`):

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.proxy_arp=1
```